# Should i implement view model for fast querying?

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first

I am currently referring to a code sample in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1030862/CRUD-operation-on-multiple-tables-with-AngularJS-a) website.

However i saw that he used both views and modelview. Then, i've come across a blog that stated among the 10 do's and don'ts for faster SQL queries, ***don’t use ORMs (object-relational mappers)*** when i searched for ORM code samples, it seemed like entity framework. So, is this a wise example to follow? Or should i just stick to simple queries? Because, the thing is, in my project, a function has to query multiple tables.

Should i stick to code-first but implement conventional querying? Or is it alright to follow the website i showed?

**ADDED**

Is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/821439/Getting-started-with-ASP-Net-Web-API-using-CodeF) tutorial following 'best practices'? I found this when i searched for DTO tutorials. I was wondering since its concept looked similar to AngularJs, should i implement either one of them or could i implement both together?

Comment: Most likely what you should do: Use an ORM, don't reinvent the wheel. What you should aim for is to use a DTO/ViewModel. A DTO is often use in the "database" layer, where you project your query into a DTO class, which is a simpler representation of your domain entity Aka: Table. This saves you from querying data you don't need and also don't expose your domain classes to your API clients.

Comment: EF is by far the most used one in the .Net world. But, if you looking for something else, check out Dapper. It's a "mini/micro orm" created by the StackExchange team.

Comment: @jpgrassi So, in other words, what he did is right so i should just continue with it?

Comment: The article focus more on the Spa, not much in back-end code. But as I could see.. yes. The idea is right. Note that there's no right and wrong answer for this.. only "best practices".

Comment: @jpgrassi So what you actually meant to say is that its better that i implement DTO, right? I've come across another tutorial(i've edited my question to include another website i found), could you comment about it?

Comment: @jpgrassi Could you kindly recommend me any good tutorials on DTO with EF? I searched for some but most have bad comments and reviews till now i dont know which one i could use as a tutorial..